# Setting load screen height with js - how to prevent flash of wrong height before JS runs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've had this issue a few times now and want to resolve.

Setting the height of the load screen by comparing to window height like so in my JS file:

```
var browserHeight = $(window).height();
var headerHeight = $('#brand-header').outerHeight(true);
$('#intro').height(browserHeight-headerHeight);
```

But on page load, there's a flash of the content at its natural (and incorrect) height before sizing appropriately. Not what I'm working on now, but an example of a recent site done with the issue unresolved (WARNING this site has sound on load (despite my best efforts to dissuade)): http://www.brooklyn.cuny.edu/web/academics/schools/mediaarts/schools/feirstein.php

What's the best way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just use position: relative and width and height 100% ?

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.full.red {
  background-color: orangered;
}
.full.green {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="full red"></div>
<div class="full green"></div>
```

Comment: Nice. Should have realized that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to add a class that sets `visibility: hidden` to both elements making them take up space on the page but invisible. That however changes your flash of wrong height into a flash of background-color.

Another option could be to make sure that the `#intro` takes up 100% of the screen by using `vh` or adding a set of `height: 100%` properties and to absolutely position the `#brand-header`. I think most of the time this is done to horizontally and vertically center something, e.g. the `#intro`, to the screen itself not to the screen minus the header, so try asking that question.

And you can always fallback to adding a opaque overlay div that's removed after the heights are all set.